# InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, api, types, autofill

Hoping for some help on this error please.  I am getting an Error when I try to run my Autofill suggestions.  I have three print statements to check how far the code is getting.  I get the 'working?222' print but it doesn't make it to the 'did I get here' print statement.  I receive the following error. The Error I'm getting is a Type Error which I haven't been able to fix. Error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'.  I know it's a type mismatch but I have been unsuccessful in fixing it.  Here is my code where it fails.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
class SugCompound {
  final String compound;

  const SugCompound({
    required this.compound,
  });

  static SugCompound fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SugCompound(
    compound: json['compound'],
  );
}

class SugCompoundApi {
  static Future<List<SugCompound>> getSugCompoundSuggestions(String query) async {
    //   print('working?');
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://website.com/rest/autocomplete/compound/$query/json?limit=6');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print('working?222');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List sugCompounds = json.decode(response.body);
      print('did I get here');
      return sugCompounds.map((json) => 
SugCompound.fromJson(json)).where((sugCompound)  {
    final compoundLower = sugCompound.compound.toLowerCase();
    final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
    return compoundLower.contains(queryLower);
  }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception();
     // }
   }
  }
}

json looks like this:
{
    "status": {
        "code": 0
    },
    "total": 6,
    "dictionary_terms": {
        "compound": [
            "aspirin",
            "Aspirina",
            "AspirinTest2",
            "ASPIRIN (MART.)",
            "ASPIRIN COMPONENT OF AXOTAL",
            "ASPIRIN COMPONENT OF AZDONE"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

error is where you are assigning a map to list:

```
final List sugCompounds = json.decode(response.body);
```

which is now allowed, you can Change your class like:

```
class SugCompound {
  final List<String> compound;

  const SugCompound({
    required this.compound,
  });

  static SugCompound fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SugCompound(
        compound: json['dictionary_terms']['compound'],
  );
}
```

And your future will be like:

```
Future<List> getSugCompoundSuggestions(String query) async {
  //   print('working?');
  final url = Uri.parse(
      'https://website.com/rest/autocomplete/compound/$query/json?limit=6');
  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    SugCompound loadedSugCompound = SugCompound.fromJson(response.body);
    List<String> compoundList = loadedSugCompound.compound;
    compoundList = compoundList
        .where((element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    return compoundList;
  } else {
    throw Exception();
    // }
  }
```

Now the future returns a list of what you searched, put this in [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and show it into screen

Comment: Thank you Mohammad, I have tried to add what you've given me but it says a value of List<String> and return from method getSugCompSug... because of type Future<List<SugCompound>>.  I have spent three hours with this crazy type mismatch.  I can't figure it out.  I'm new to this.  If I change the Future List to String, it messes up some of my other dart files.  I don't know why this type thing is so difficult to change.  I must be missing something easy.

Comment: if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List sugCompounds = json.decode(response.body);
      SugCompound loadedSugCompound = SugCompound.fromJson(response as Map<String, dynamic>);
      List<String> compoundList = loadedSugCompound.compound;
       return compoundList = compoundList
          .where(
              (element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      //

Comment: Oh sorry, i updated my answer

Comment: If have any other error, im happy to help

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I really appreciate your help.  I'm having quite a time with this for some reason.  Anyway, when I change to your latest suggestions, two of my other pages give errors on the suggestionsCallback: SugCompoundApi.getSugCompoundSuggestions,

Comment: what error they had?

Comment: Reading the documentation, I think I need to change the name of something.  Sorry to ask so many questions.  I definitely need to get a better understanding of this.  Thanks again!

Comment: error is: Instance member 'getSugCompoundSuggestions' can't be accessed using static access.

Comment: your welcome. use `getSugCompoundSuggestions` function like i did, out of class without static

Comment: I tried that but I think the Callback requires a class because it can't find my callback to just getSugCompoundSuggestions.  When I removed the class for the Future<List> getSugCompoundSuggestions and remove the SugCompundAPI. from the call back as such: suggestionsCallback: getSugCompoundSuggestions,  I get the error : The argument type 'Future<List<dynamic>> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<Iterable<SugCompound?>> Function(String)'

Comment: I dont know what exactly you are trying,

Comment: I tried using without status and out of the class.  It produced the error on my other pages when trying to use the callback to the Future<List>.  suggestionsCallback: getSugCompoundSuggestions, I get the error : The argument type 'Future<List<dynamic>> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<Iterable<SugCompound?>> Function(String)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248572/discussion-between-mohammad-esmaili-and-sherrib).